# Windows batch file match prefix and suffix in filenames

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Within an Windows batch file, is it possible to extract `somestring` when files are named this way:

```
prefix_somestring.txt
somestring_suffix.txt
```

Assuming the underscore `_` separating the prefix or suffix. The context is to iterate through all files in a folder and return `somestring` for each file.

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: In which context? What you want to do? Both `DIR prefix_*` and `FOR %1 IN (prefix_*) DO ECHO %1` may works...

Comment: Are you **really** using `MS-DOS`? Why did you also tag the question with `windows` then?

Comment: So the context is this: I want to run an .exe on these files. The .exe takes command-line parameters and its those two files shown above. Also it takes as third parameter a new file which it creates. The new file should be called `somestring.txt`.

Comment: Removed `windows` tag

Comment: I have changed the question to now one single question. Also realizing that `DIR prefix_*` and `DIR *_suffix` works.

Comment: MS-DOS uses 8.3 filenames and cannot have longer filenames.  You must be talking about Windows using CMD.EXE

Comment: To create a solution where `somestring` is variable and it can have a prefix OR a suffix then the prefix and suffix must be known.

Comment: Yes its Windows 7 using `CMD.exe`

Comment: What about the prefix and suffix I mentioned?  Are they known?

Comment: re-added the `windows` tag and removed the references to "DOS" because `cmd.exe` in Windows has nothing to do with `MS-DOS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the _ with space. Then the filename string will be two words. Now run a for loop and store the two words in two variables.

Please excuse brevity due to typing through mobile app.

```
for %%a in ("%cd%\*.txt") do (
set myfile=%%~nxa
set myfile=!myfile:_= !

set part1=""
set part2=""
for %%i in (%myfile%) do (
    if "%part1%"=="" (
        set part1=%%i
    ) else (
        set part2=%%i
    )
)
echo %part1% %part2%
)
```